# How to show multiple city on map using Google Maps API v3

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3

i've a list of cities in php like:

```
$cities = array(0=>"Absecon,NJ",1=>"Alamogordo,NJ",2=>"Atlantic city,NJ....);
```

i have to show all my cities on maps, is possible if i don't have lat and lon?

i initialize maps in this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var countries = '<?php echo json_enconde($cities);?>';
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 2,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Those don't look like "countries" to me, your examples seem to be cities or towns in the United States (as you indicated in the title).

The [Geocoding web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) will return geographic coordinates for a place name, but is subject to a quota and rate limits.

The usual advice is to geocode your places off-line, store the resulting coordinates and use those to display the map.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat) is an article from the documentation on geocoding strategies.